# 1046 No database selected mysql cpanel

Tags: mysql

how to fix this error when i import database into phpmyadmin cpanel:

```
    SQL query:

--
-- Database: `news_letter`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `banner_tbl`
--
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `banner_tbl` (

    `ban_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
    `banner_img` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
    `date` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
     ) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT =158 DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected
```

Comment: have you created DB with name `news_letter`?

Comment: where in local or in cpanel?

Comment: where do you want to upload your database?

Comment: where ever you want to upload, you have to make the database..

Comment: also you need to `USE` the database  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html

Comment: yeah, got it man. thank you for suggest.

Answer (score 2):

add the following lines on top of your .sql file

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `news_letter`;
USE `news_letter`;
```